# Should a binary file provided by a Web API app be stored in the App_Data folder, or where?

Tags: c#, download, httpresponse, binaryfiles, app-data

Clients will request the conditional download of a binary file from my Web API app.

The method that responds to this request will probably be something like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetHHSetupUpdate(double clientVersion)
{
    double currentVersion = getCurrentVersion("platypiRUs");
    if (clientVersion >= currentVersion)
    {
      return null;
    }  
    var path = @"C:\Platypi\PlatypiRUs.exe";
    var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

What is unnerving me most at present is the location of the file, though. Should it be stored in the project's App_Data folder, or elsewhere?

If so (stored in App_Data), how is that referenced in code? Would it be like:

```
var path = @"\App_Data\PlatypiRUs.exe";
```

...or...???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\App_Data\PlatypiRUs.exe")
```

alternatively, you could also use [`HostingEnvironment.MapPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.mappath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

Comment: HostingEnvironment must be preferable, because Server.MapPath doesn't resolve - it offers up Microsoft.SQLServer.Server, but that's not what I need.